# Evaluating formula in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to process salary details of employees depends upon some schedule using SQL Server 2005. Here some fields are evaluating from formula. like..eg.

HRA=(BS+Earning1)*10/100

here formula is getting from Table, it'll vary for diff accounts(HRA, Medical Allavance etc). Value of formula operators (eg. BS, Earning1) are in table. I want to replace operator strings with its value and to get formula result.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the table and data. This should help.

```
SELECT account, (BS+Earning1)*10/100 as [SaleryFormula] 
FROM Table
```

BS will be replaced with the value in BS column for that account. 
That assumes each account has a single record in the Table. Otherwise

```
SELECT account, (SUM(BS)+SUM(Earning1))*10/100 as [SaleryFormula] 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Thnaks, I got the answer same way.